# Django: template does not show new records automatically in template after POST

Tags: python, django

I'm creating records of my model `School` on a template.

The problem is that the page does not show the elements created after the "Submit" button is clicked. I've to do a refresh to show the new objects on template. why?

**urls.py:**

```
path('escuelas-csv/', views.schools_upload, name="schools_upload"),
```

**views.py:**

```
### Read CSV file to create records ###

import csv, io
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import messages

def schools_upload(request):

    template = "scolarte/escuelas/escuelas.html"
    data = School.objects.all()
    prompt = {
        'orden': 'El orden de las columnas del archivo CSV debe ser: escuela, direccion, referencia, provincia, cantón, parroquia',
        'escuelas': data    
              }

    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, template, prompt)
    csv_file = request.FILES['file']

    if not csv_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
        messages.error(request, 'El archivo no es un archivo CSV')
    data_set = csv_file.read().decode('iso-8859-1')
    io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
    next(io_string)
    for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar="|"):
        _, created = School.objects.update_or_create(
            name=column[0],
            address=column[1],
            address_reference=column[2],
            provincia=column[3],
            canton=column[4],
            parroquia=column[5],
        )
    context = {}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

**html:** `scolarte/escuelas/escuelas.html`

```
{% block content %}
{% if messages %}
{% for message in messages %}
<div>
    <!--                | means OR operator-->
    <strong>{{message|safe}}</strong>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% else %}

<h1>Creación de escuelas</h1>
<p>{{orden}}</p>
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="file1">Subir archivo</label>
    <input type="file" id="file1" name="file"><br>
    <small>Solo se aceptan CSV files</small>
    <button type="submit">Crear escuelas</button>
</form>
{% endif %}
<h3> Escuelas disponibles </h3>
<table class="tg margin-top5">
    <tr>
        <th class="tg-0pky">Escuela</th>
        <th class="tg-0pky">Dirección</th>
        <th class="tg-0pky">Provincia</th>
        <th class="tg-0pky">Fecha de creación</th>
    </tr>
    {% for escuela in escuelas %}
    <tr>
        <td class="tg-0pky">{{escuela.name}}</td>
        <td class="tg-0pky">{{escuela.address}}</td>
        <td class="tg-0pky">{{escuela.provincia}}</td>
        <td class="tg-0pky">{{escuela.created_at}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of a POST request, you are re-rendering the template with an empty context - so actually, you just shouldn't see *any* row in your table at this point, so there's probably something else in your code you didn't show.

The solution is, quite simply, to do [what a view is supposed to do after a successful post](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-redirect-get): redirect (in your case to the same url). This will force the browser to refresh the page (which solves your problem), but also prevent other issues like resubmitting the form etc.

As a side note: feeding your database unsanitized user inputs is asking for trouble. Django forms are not only for HTML forms, they can be used to validate any plain dict.

Comment: that is not what this line at the end is supposed to do? `return render(request, template, context)`???

Comment: No, it isn't. It's returning a `200` response, with response content's populate from rendering the template with the given context. A `redirect` returns a 302 response. This is documented https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/

Answer (score 1):

You have to refresh the page or redirect back to it after any POST request without using something like ajax. Check this out to help you get started

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html

Comment: Really no need for ajax here. Well, IMHO ;-)